# What are the advantages (if any) of being an unregistered user?

Tags: discussion, unregistered-users

What are the advantages of being an unregistered user?

Comment: Not many.  Seeing "user12345" as the questioner is -100 points when I browse questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main advantage of being an unregistered user is that **you don't have to sign up**. So if you feel sketchy about OpenID, or simply have only one question that needs attending to, it's a great way to get expert answers without tying yourself down to some place.

Sometimes, people don't have the time to dedicate to full participation in a Q&A site, and by allowing people to act unregistered we are able to provide our services even to these people. We give them an easier avenue than, say, registering at a random forum. It's not a big hassle, but not having to do it at all is very advantageous.

Ideally, these users do the smallest part of payback by accepting a good answer, but we don't even enforce that on them.

Aside from the lack of ties, the only other "advantages" are not having to deal with the downsides of being a user, such as:

- Receiving emails for anything
- Global inbox reminders every second from every site
- Revenge downvotes and other vindictive acts
- Addiction

Comment: @Welbog I was going to wait until tonight when I got home, but Happy Birthday!

Comment: It's fine 'cause it's not quite my birthday yet. I was just seeing how many more days I had to wait before I could change my name but it turns out I could change it already so I kinda jumped the gun.

Comment: Unregistered users do get Global inbox notifications.