# How do I give someone reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

Someone answered one of my questions and I would like to give him reputation. How do I do that? Does the computer do that itself? This is my second day using this site, so I can't quite navigate this site.

Comment: Read the faq - it's linked on every page.

Answer (score 7):

You click on the hollow "V" icon to the left of the answer.

Comment: @Arjan sorry as usual you're correct.. they can't cast votes though. I'll edit my answer with the relevant question asked yesterday.

Comment: @PopularDemand Shouldn't this technically be the green "^"?

Comment: It's referring to the accepted answer checkmark, not the upvote button. The OP is new, so he probably hasn't earned the privilege of casting upvotes yet. (Although the check isn't green until _after_ it's clicked; I re-edited.) @Chris

Answer (score 4):

voting up (up arrow) answers you like or accepting their answer both increases their reputation.

It is important to accept an answer when you think it answers your question pretty well.
If it not but it's very helpful anyways you can just vote it up and leave the question open.

It is not really a matter of rewarding people, but rewarding good questions and good answers.

Answer (score 1):

See this question for reference: [Why is OP unable to upvote any answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82185/why-is-op-unable-to-upvote-any-answers)

You first need to Register your account: click on the **Log In** link in the top menu on every page, and choose how you prefer to register, e.g. using existing `gmail` account, giving your email address and more options.

Once you have permanent and registered account on the site you can give (and get) reputation like all others have said already.

As long as you're not registered member, you **can't** do many things that are related to reputation.

Comment: Even when registered, I think you still need 15 reputation to be able to upvote anything, even when you're the OP.

Comment: @Arj 15 indeed, both here and on the parent site..

Answer (score 0):

The main way to give others rep, as mentioned in the other answers, it to upvote the other user's posts (10 points for answer upvote, 5 for question), and accept an answer (which gives the person who posted that answer 15 reputation points).

You could also start a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty), though it'll cost you some of your own rep. One reason for starting a bounty is to "[reward existing answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)," which is what it sounds like you want to do.

Answer (score -3):

You go to the post in question and approve their answer.

Comment: If the OP knew what "approving an answer" was, he probably wouldn't have asked this question.