# Why is registered user unable to upvote answers to own question?

Tags: support, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits)

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566282/boxes-side-by-side) on SO, the (registered) OP is claiming in the comments to each answer that they don't have enough reputation to upvote the answer - is this possible?

The OP is *registered*, they have only 1 rep, but the question itself has been downvoted twice. However, I thought that all registered users could upvote answers to their *own* question regardless of rep (or with a rep of 1)?

I found a similar question on meta: [Why is OP unable to upvote any answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82185/why-is-op-unable-to-upvote-any-answers) - but in this case the OP is unregistered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only vote if you have at least [15 points](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up).

You can *comment* on your own posts before you've gained the privilege to do so elsewhere, but that doesn't extend to voting.

Comment: But answers to your own questions?! I have read the FAQ, but admittedly assumed that the 15 point requirement to upvote was related to other peoples questions and answers to other questions.

Comment: 15 points is not much, is it? No, answers to your own questions also cannot be upvoted.

Comment: You can also accept answers still too, which is effectively a binding vote.

Comment: I agree that 15 points is not much, however, I find that I am often answering questions of new users (rep 1) - particularly on [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) - where many of these newbies seem to have an innate inability to mark accepted answers. Hhhmmm...

Comment: @w3d: Teaching new users about SE features is a different issue, isn't it? How do you know they'd know about upvoting too?

Comment: @w3d - The 15 point limit is slightly useful to keep spammers from upvoting themselves. You have to get a few upvotes (2 or 3) yourself before you can start giving rep to others.