# Which one is the real number of users on Stackoverflow?

Tags: support, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Discrepancy between user counts on Leagues versus Users page.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81260/discrepancy-between-user-counts-on-leagues-versus-users-page)

According to https://stackoverflow.com/users, SO currently has ~421k users. (I see 9x4 users on a page, with currently 11,710 pages<sup>1</sup>, which makes 421,560 users.)

According to https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/, there's currently 619,716 users.

Where does the difference come from?

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that this number is increasing by the minute. That's why I originally only gave a rounded number.

Comment: The extra 200K are Jon Skeets running on separate threads.

Comment: Don't you know anything about quantum physics. Everytime you measure the number of SO users, you alter the result.

Comment: The leagues are so popular they entice an extra 200k users.

Comment: So my follow-up question would be: What's an unregistered user? Since I doubt that I'm the first to ask that, could someone please direct me to a previous question, so I don't create another dupe?

Comment: Never mind, found it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/unregistered-user

Comment: I see you found an answer, but you might also consider [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70481/what-are-the-advantages-if-any-of-being-an-unregistered-user), and [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account), as additional reading for the pros and cons respectively of being an unregistered user.

Comment: @Grace: Thanks, those are indeed interesting!